# Query a single cell in a SQL DB using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

If you mark my question as duplicate, then make sure the one you link it to is not an example specific to someone else's application.

```
----------------------
|       Table        |
----------------------
| ID |  Name | Color |
----------------------
| 1  |  Ae   |  Red  |
| 2  |  Be   |  Red  |
| 3  |  Ce   |  Red  |
| 4  |  De   |  Red  |
----------------------
```

My question is, say I want to make a SQL query to select **ONLY** the ID number from the first row using PHP. How do I do that?

This is what I've tried:

php

```
    $host = "localhost";
    $name = "db";
    $user = "root"
    $pass = "password";

    $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password) or die("Failed");
    mysqli_select_db($connection, $name) or die("Failed");

    $id = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT id FROM db WHERE id=0");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($id);

    echo "$id";
```

Why does that not work? What needs to be changed to output 1 and only 1? Please ELI5, SQL burns my brain..

Comment: Because; you didn't fetch (looped over) results. You're just echoing the query.

Comment: Define "the first row" -- first by what criteria?

Comment: Also, based on your example there's no row with `id=0`.

Comment: ^ heh; good one.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner would adding `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); echo "$row";` be correct?
@AlexHowansky Sorry, Gotta be specific with Stack.. the top row of the table, or '0' row

Comment: Something like that, yes.

Comment: There is no such thing as "top" row. When not explicitly specified, a specific ordering of the table can not be assumed. Do you mean, you want the lowest id?

Comment: @AlexHowansky if you can't infer the value I'm trying to fetch, don't bother answering, I understand my specifics are lacking but don't be pedantic. Yes, lowest id, or, as I specified in my question, the cell with the value of `1`

Comment: As @tadman [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54154054/query-a-single-cell-in-a-sql-db-using-php#comment95139157_54154054), you have no `0`. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Computer science is nothing *but* pedantry. SQL databases have no guaranteed ordering. If you want the "top" row, then *you* have to explicitly tell the database what sort order to use -- don't assume it will automatically sort by what you consider to be the obvious column.

Comment: Also, please note that insulting people who are trying to help you generally yields poor results.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I apologize

Comment: A simple ORDER BY would suffice here, pretty sure (as shown [in Tadman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54154097/1415724)). If not, you can try `MIN()` given an INT type column.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of SQL you must define "first" in terms of "order", as in:

```
SELECT id FROM db ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
```

Where you're asking for the results to be ordered by the `id` column, which defaults to ascending order (1, 2, 3, ...) and limiting your results to one row with the `LIMIT` clause. For the highest value you'd `ORDER BY id DESC` in descending order and pluck off the first value.

Applying this in your case you can use [`bind_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) to capture the ID value:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password) or die("Failed");

$conn->select_db($name);

$res = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM db ORDER BY id LIMIT 1");

// Declare your intention to capture the result into $id
$res->bind_result($id);
// Fetch the data which applies the binding
$res->fetch();
```

SQL might seem confusing at first. If you're thinking it's like writing procedural code, like PHP, that's the wrong mind-set. It's a *query language*, which is not like programming per-se, but about declaring what you want and letting the server figure it out and give you the data back.

The good news is that SQL has been around for decades and is very well documented, even the MySQL dialect that you're using here. In addition to the MySQL manual there are innumerable books on the subject of databases and SQL in terms of both theory and practice. If it's still confusing you probably need to find a better introduction and reference.

Comment: Notice [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54154054/query-a-single-cell-in-a-sql-db-using-php#comment95139130_54154054)? Being part of the issue.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner What do you mean? His solution in itself still wouldn't echo the value I want?

Comment: This gets you the value, but you need to fetch it as Funk Forty Niner says.

Comment: @Jay what exactly *do* you want to echo? 1 row? a few? all? other/not listed?

Comment: I've added a rough example here of how this might play out completely.

Comment: @tadman I appreciate the patience, looks like I got what I was after. Thank you